# pair radio buttons in seperate panels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, radio-button, controls

I have a windows forms applications which shows some user controls in the form. Each user control has a radio button. Is it possible to manually pair the radio buttons so only one of them can be selected at the same time? My other option would be to check each radio button when a radio button is clicked so that all other radio buttons are unchecked.

Comment: Show us What you have tried??!!

Comment: Place the RadioButtons in a GroupBox to establish grouping.

Comment: @rheitzman that is not a solution for me since my radio buttons are in different usercontrols. Each usercontrol has multiple controls (textbox, labels, etc.) foreach item that is added to the form a usercontrol is created. I needed a way to inform the user on which usercontrol is selected so I added a radiobutton to the usercontrol. The anwser Loathing profided was a perfect sollution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton { Text = "RB1" };
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton { Text = "RB2" };
        RadioButtonGroup rgb = new RadioButtonGroup(rb1, rb2);

        foreach (RadioButton rb in new [] { rb1, rb2 }) {
            Form f = new Form { Text = rb.Text };
            f.Controls.Add(rb);
            f.Show();
            rb.CheckedChanged += delegate {
                MessageBox.Show(rb.Text + ": " + rb.Checked);
            };
        }



private class RadioButtonGroup {
    RadioButton[] radioButtons = null;
    public RadioButtonGroup(params RadioButton[] radioButtons) {
        this.radioButtons = radioButtons;
        foreach (var rb in radioButtons) {
            rb.AutoCheck = false;
            rb.Click += rb_Click;
        }
    }

    void rb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (RadioButton rb in radioButtons)
            rb.Checked = (rb == sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add a `AddRadioButton(RadioButton rb)` method so I could add radiobuttons on runtime. In my solution usercontrolls can be added on at any time. I was surprised about the function of `rb.Checked = (rb == sender);` Could you explane why `(rb == sender)` return a boolean?

Comment: @MaikoKingma Anytime you register an `event` listener with a `winforms` control, the delegate listener method follows the pattern `NameOfVariable_NameOfEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)` (or some variation of it with a more specific `EventArgs`). The `sender` parameter is the `control` that fired / triggered the event. So `(rb == sender)` is saying make the radio button checked if it was the one that was clicked, since it fired the event. Obviously that wouldn't work for `checkboxes`, as they have a toggle behavior. But a `radiobutton` is always checked on click.

Comment: thanks very much, i'm definitely going to use that more often.